# Forgot Salesforce developer edition security answer

Tags: security, forgot-your-password

May I know how I can reset password without security question answer ? I forgot both password and security answer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to contact Salesforce Customer Support by creating a case since you are the only Admin.

More info on this [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005251&type=1).